# AJAX Post gives 404 error for one function but similar function runs okay

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using `jQuery` and `AJAX` to run `PHP` functions without refreshing the page. It was working fine for my first two instances but I added a new one an now the new instance keeps giving me the following error

```
POST http://www.example.com/ajax.php 404 (Not Found)
```

I checked and rechecked and try to fin a similar error somewhere else by I am stumped. Here is my html

```
<img id="green" src="http://www.example.com/image/sign_no.jpg" onclick="runAjax(this.id)" />
<span id="blue" onclick="runAjax(this.id)">Press Here</span>
```

Here is my jQuery code

```
<script language="javascript">
    function runAjax(id) {
        if (id == "green") {
            if (document.getElementById("green").src == "http://www.example.com/image/sign_no.jpg") {
                document.getElementById("green").src = "http://www.example.com/image/sign_yes.jpg";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/ajax.php",
                    data:{action:"green_pressed",user_id:"' . $user_id . '"},
                    success:function(html) {
                        alert(id);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        else if (id == "blue") {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ajax.php",
                data:{action:"blue_pressed",run_id:"' . $run_id . '"},
                success:function(html) {
                    alert(id);
                }
            });

        }
    }
</script>
```

This is the ajax.php file

```
if($_POST['action'] == 'green_pressed') {
        print_r($_POST['user_id']);
}
if($_POST['action'] == 'blue_pressed') {
        print_r($_POST['run_id']);
}
```

So when I press the `green` id there is no issues, the code runs fine but when I press the `blue` id there is where I get the error. Any insights?

Comment: No idea without seeing the php

Comment: It needs to be asked... does the file `/ajax.php` exist in the web root and can you access it directly from the browser?

Comment: The problem is not the `/ajax.php` since when I click the green button it runs without any issue. Why would it be an issue when I press the blue button? I will add the ajax just in case

Comment: Check your error logs, i cant see anything obviously wrong here

Comment: Is this the actual code or a public representation of it for SO ? Because it seems.. Fine.. ?

Comment: @Pogrindis this is the actual code so far. I am not sure why it is giving me a 404 error. If I don't run ajax if runs fine. Thanks

Comment: So your actual code literally contains `"/ajax.php"` for both `$.ajax()` calls, correct? Not `"http://www.example.com/ajax.php"` or anything else?